# Analyzing multi-languages project with sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity

I am working on a project in c# and javascript. 
I am analyzing my project with SonarQube using a build step in Teamcity.
But I am able to do analyze only one language, either CS or JS.

If I set the below configuration, it does not work:

```
sonar.language=cs,js
```

How to setup the analysis for both languages, without so that it shows analysis of languages under same project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "sonar.language" property from the configuration of your analysis. It will enable multi-language analysis.

This is the default behavior since SonarQube 4.2:

- http://www.sonarqube.org/at-long-last-sonarqube-is-a-true-polyglot/

Comment: I did it, but its still not running analysis for javascript, but in sonar cube I see javascript rules. do i need to install some language scanner plugin of sonar to do it?

Comment: Make sure that js sources are in folders defined in "sonar.sources".
You can set "sonar.log.level=DEBUG" while running your analysis in order to enable debug logs and see if js files are detected.